# Is there a way for me to offload an App Service Plan to Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, instance, azure-log-analytics, azure-app-service-plans, kql

I wan to see logs of the nodes of my app service plan in Log Analytics. I DONT want to do it with app service. I need to query data of my nodes with KQL

Comment: what do you mean of nodes of my app service plan?

Comment: By that I mean the VM instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible as of now. Please vote up for this user voice: [Request to manage diagnostic settings for App Service Plan from Azure portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/39710563-request-to-manage-diagnostic-settings-for-app-serv).

I also tried from both azure portal and rest api:

**From** azure portal, there is no the option of `Diagnostic settings` for `app service plan`.

**From** api [Diagnostic Settings - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnosticsettings/createorupdate): It throws an error says that `app service plan` is not in the whitelist which means that it's not supported currently.

Hope Microsoft can implement this feature for `service plan` asap:).